# In WPF, how to customize the style of ScrollBar in ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I can add a ScrollBar style as global. But that will alse change all the ScrollBar except in ScrollViewer.
How can I just change the style of ScrollBar in ScrollViewer. Maybe add a style with a Key and specify it to somewhere like a ControlTemplate.

Here is my fully ScrollBar style:

```
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border x:Name="rectangle"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            Background="{StaticResource WordBlueBrush}"
                            Opacity="0.3"
                            CornerRadius="4"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>   
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="rectangle" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false"/>

    <Setter Property="Width" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-14 0 0 0" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">

                    <Border Padding="0 4">
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
                        IsDirectionReversed="true"
                        IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                        Width="8"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           >
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Opacity="0" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}" />
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Opacity="0" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}" />
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb  }" />
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Add a style for `ScrollViewer`. see [ScrollViewer Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/scrollviewer-styles-and-templates)

Comment: If I add a ScrollViewer style. I need to find all the fullly default style for ScrollViewer and just change the ScrollBar part in the ControlTemplete of ScrollViewer. Where would I get it. Otherwise, if in other scenes, I need to change a child Control's style of a parent Control, I should find the default style of the parent Control. Is this the only way to do so. Or is there a simple way to just spacify the style of ScrollBar in ScrollViewer? Or generally, specify the style of a child Control in a parent Control？

Comment: Can you edit  your question and add your `ScrollBar` style?

Comment: I has added the ScrollBar style.

Comment: I test it and its work for me. i just change `<RepeatButton Opacity="0" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}" />` to `<RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}" />` and remove `Opacity` (i don't know why you set that, anywhay it's yours). But in the `ScrollViewer` the scroll bars appear only when they are needed. for example when the content of the `ScrollViewer` is not entirely visible, the `ScrollViewer` displays scrollbars. So you don't need to create a style for your `ScrollViewer` if you don't need to customize it.

Comment: Also this style don't work in horizontal orientation.

Comment: It's seems I didn't say clearly of my question. I knows the ScrollBar style will work. But it will work not just in ScrollViewer. For example the style will effect on the ScrollBar of TextBox too, and I don't wish that happened. I want it just change the style of the ScrollBar inside ScrollViewer.    ps: I set the opacity of RepeatButton to 0 beacuse I want hide it's apperance and keep it's clickable functionality.

Comment: I deleted the horizontal orientation part. The code is too long that I can't upload it.

Comment: OK. so just customize your 'ScrollViewer' by createing a style for it. set your scroll bar style key (ex. `<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" key="something" ...</Style>`) and in the scroll viewer control templete set to `<ScrollBar x:Name="..." ControlTemplate={Static Resource something} .../>`

Comment: That must be the only way to solve it. Thank you very much. It's midnight in my area. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I got my solution.

1st, add a key to the ScrollBar style:

```
<Style x:Key="ViewerScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
```

2nd, right click the ScrollViewer in Visual Studio XAML Designer. Chose 'Edit Template'->'Edit a Copy':

[Add ControlTemplate for ScrollViewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsU9O.png)

3rd, in the 'Create Style Resource' dialog, specify a key for the ScrollViewer style and click 'OK':

[Create Style Resource Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjI1M.png)

4th, Visual Studio will automatically create the ControlTemplate for my ScrollViewer. Now, add Style="{StaticResource ViewerScrollBar}" for the horizontal ScrollBar and verticalScrollBar:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollViewerControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <ScrollBar Style="{StaticResource ViewerScrollBar}" x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
            <ScrollBar Style="{StaticResource ViewerScrollBar}" x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```